# Wrap behaviour in Ace.js, take indentation into account?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Does the ace editor provide an option for the wrap mode which takes the indentation into consideration?

Like This:
[image: Like this]

Currently `wrap: true` produces this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature was added recently in https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/pull/2187

Comment: so `wrap: true` should do this in the latest version?